# jQuery - Using regex to make a pattern in a link bold

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list with dates and i try to use jQuery & regular expressions to make every date in a link bold. This is what i got so far:

```js
$date = '/([0-2][0][0-9][0-9]).([0-1][0-9]).([0-3][0-9])/gi';

$('a:contains('+$date+')').css('font-weight','600');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#">2018.03.08 Event #1</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">2018.02.12 Event #2</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">2017.12.04 Event #3</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

What's wrong with my code?
Is there a better way to do this?

I'm a noob at JS/jQuery so thank you very much for any help!

Comment: If jQuery code doesn't seem to be working then the best thing to do is read the documentation for the jQuery you're using; [`:contains()`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) looks for a string of text within the supplied elements in order to filter that collection. It takes only a string, not a regular expression Object.

Comment: Have you tried making the font-weight value 700, instead of 600? I believe 700 is the font-weight equivalent of bold.

Comment: @DavidThomas Oh thank you very much! Do you maybe have a tip how i could accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, a solution to the problem:

```
// a date-pattern regular expression literal:
let datePattern = /([0-2][0-9]{3,3}\.[0-1][0-9]\.[0-3][0-9])/gi;

// select all <a> elements,
// and iterate over the returned collection with the
// .html() method:
$('a').html(function() {

  // here we return the modified string of text,
  // wrapping any patterns matching the date pattern,
  // with the '<b>' and '</b>' tags; as this text is
  // returned to the HTML method this is parsed as
  // HTML:
  return this.textContent.replace(datePattern, '<b>$1</b>');
});
```

```js
let datePattern = /([0-2][0-9]{3,3}\.[0-1][0-9]\.[0-3][0-9])/gi;

$('a').html(function() {
  return this.textContent.replace(datePattern, '<b>$1</b>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#">2018.03.08 Event #1</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">2018.02.12 Event #2</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">2017.12.04 Event #3</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

It's also worth noting that, while jQuery can – and *does* – make some things easier, the above is simple to do with plain JavaScript:

```
let datePattern = /([0-2][0-9]{3,3}\.[0-1][0-9]\.[0-3][0-9])/gi;

// converting the result of the contained expression
// into an Array, in order to gain access to Array methods:
Array.from(

  // retrieving all <a> elements from the document:
  document.querySelectorAll('a')

// using Array.prototype.forEach() to iterate over
// the Array of <a> elements:
).forEach(function(aElement) {
  // 'aElement' refers to the current <a> element
  // of the Array of <a> elements.

  // here we update the innerHTML of the current <a> element
  // to be equal to the text of the current <a> element, after
  // wrapping any date-patterns - as before - with the '<b>'
  // and '</b>' tags:
  aElement.innerHTML = aElement.textContent.replace(datePattern, '<b>$1</b>');
});
```

```js
let datePattern = /([0-2][0-9]{3,3}\.[0-1][0-9]\.[0-3][0-9])/gi;

Array.from(
  document.querySelectorAll('a')
).forEach(function(aElement) {
  aElement.innerHTML = aElement.textContent.replace(datePattern, '<b>$1</b>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#">2018.03.08 Event #1</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">2018.02.12 Event #2</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">2017.12.04 Event #3</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And now to the problems:

```
$date = '/([0-2][0][0-9][0-9]).([0-1][0-9]).([0-3][0-9])/gi';
```

Here you declared a global variable (bad practice, since that global can be used/overwritten elsewhere unpredictably). Also the regular expression  was wrapped in a string literal, which means the regular expression is a string, and not a regular expression at all.

Further the `:contains()` selector only works with strings, as the documentation clearly says.

So, in your original code, you had a String (which looked like a regular expression) which was being searched-for, but never found, in any of the `<a>` elements.

Also, had it been found the end result of your `css()` method call would be to wrap the `<a>` element itself in a `<b>` element, rather than wrapping the date-string. Which I think was your plan.

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
  - [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).
  - [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).
  - [JavaScript regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).
  - [`String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).
- jQuery:

  - [`:contains()`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/).
  - [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/).

Comment: thank you and thank you very much for explaining your code. it helps me understanding how jQuery logic works.

Comment: You're very welcome indeed, I'm glad to have been of help :)

Comment: @DavidThomas, nice and elegant solutions, I congratulate to them. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using jQuery, here's a solution geared towards it:

```js
var pattern = /([0-2][0][0-9][0-9])\.([0-1][0-9])\.([0-3][0-9])/;

// select each `a` element
$('a').each(function () {  
  // store individual `a` elements
  var elem = $(this);  
  // replace the text (date in your case) using the regex pattern and  
  // set the content of the `a` element with the new, formatted date
  elem.html(elem.text().replace(pattern, function (date) {
    // here you can apply your various inline styles
    return '<span style="font-weight: 600">' + date + '</span>';
  }));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#">2018.03.08 Event #1</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">2018.02.12 Event #2</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">2017.12.04 Event #3</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

In your case, you don't need the the `i` modifier in your regex, since your regex pattern doesn't need to mach case-sensitive characters, just numbers only.

Also, you don't need the `g` modifier either as in you particular case, based on your example, you need to match the pattern once.

Comment: ahh, this makes way more sense. the solution was a little bit harder than i thought though. thanks a lot, you're my hero!

Answer (score 0):

Simple and good solution:

```
var regex = new RegExp("[0-9]"); // expression here

$("a").filter(function () {
    return regex.test($(this).text()); 
}).css('font-weight','100');
```